# Matrix calculus: $Bx = y$ and $AB = BA = Id \implies x= A^{-1}y?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

As stated in the title, I have an exercise with two matrices $A$ and $B$ and a system with $Bx=y$ with $x$ and $y$ being two vectors. In a previous exercise I've already shown that $AB = BA = Id$.

Now I'm supposed to show that $x := A^{-1}y$ without doing any calculations.

Since we have  $AB = BA = Id \implies B = A^{-1}$, we then get $x = B^{-1}y \iff x = Ay$

My question now is: Why is this incorrect? Since I'm supposed to show that $x = A^{-1}y$

Comment: No, obviously $x=A^{-1}$ is wrong, $A$ is a matrix and $x$ is a column... Probably you are asked to prove $x=Ay$ after all, but somehow $y$ turned into $\,^{-1}$ in (hand)writing???

Comment: @DietrichBurde The OP already knows that and also knows that $B^{-1}=A$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Exactly. So the only possible answer is $x=B^{-1}y$, or $x=Ay$. I am referring to the title (so I wanted to say the same as you, sorry). Also, the typo could be in the first part of the title: I suppose it is $Ax=y$ as usual, so that $x=A^{-1}y$ is correct.

Comment: 23408924, since you say "Since I'm supposed to show that $x = A^{-1}y$", it seems very likely that the given equation as usual is $Ax=y$ (and not $Bx=y$).

Comment: In the second paragraph you state you're supposed to prove that $x=A^{-1}$, which is generally impossible comparing dimensions of the matrices. In the last paragrah you state you're supposed to prove that $x=A^{-1}y$, which is consistent with the dimensions of the matrices, but is generally false as well.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I'm only copying what they asked us on the exercise sheet. That is why I got confused. There seems to be a mistake in the exercise then.

Comment: @egreg You're right, my mistake, I edited it. I simply forgot the $y$ at the end of the second line

Comment: Yep, almost certainly some sort of typo.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited the question again. I made a typo. But this now leads me to believe that there is a mistake in the exercise and $x = Ay$ or $ x =B^{-1}y$ is correct?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks for your help then. I will ask the TA then.

Comment: @23408924 You forgot to edit also the title, which I fixed according to the new text in the post. You're right, as from $Bx=y$ and $B=A^{-1}$ it follows that $x=Ay$ and not $x=A^{-1}y$. OK, for *very particular* matrices it could hold $A^{-1}y=Ay$, but not generally.

Comment: @egreg Oh I did not realise, sorry about that! Thanks for the edit and your help. I got confused and that's why I asked here. I will ask the TA then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mistake in the assignment.

From $AB=BA=I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix), you conclude that $B=A^{-1}$, so from
$$
y=Bx=A^{-1}x
$$
you derive
$$
Ay=x
$$
and it's generally false that $x=A^{-1}y$, which would require
$$
(A-A^{-1})y=0
$$
The last condition *may* hold for particular $A$ and $y$, but not generally.